# get multiple files from request on Grails

Tags: file, upload

Im using this but it saves only one file. I want to save multiple files.
Here is my code:

```
<input id="data"  type="file"  name="data" multiple="multiple"/>
```

and

```
 def uploadSave() {
        def document = request.getFile("data").each { file ->
       log.debug(file.originalFilename)
   }
```

What can I use to save all the files uploaded and print their original names? I tried to use MultipartFile but doesnt work. Help me, please.

```
    MultipartFile data = request.getFile("data"){
       println "File name: "+ ${data.orignalFileName}"
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the uploadr plugin for grails?

https://grails.org/plugin/uploadr

no point re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def uploadSave() {
   // notice "getFiles" instead of "getFile"
   def document = request.getFiles("data")
   document.each { file ->    
       println(file.getOriginalFilename()) // try this
       //log.debug(file.originalFilename) // tthink this is causing the error
   }
}
```

Comment: Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.String(java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: Nop. I need that definition

Comment: how about now? By the way, did it work without the definition?

Comment: Nop. Same error : Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.String(java.util.ArrayList) :(

Answer (score 0):

I would Like suggest you this jquery it one best file upload I ever come across as per as customization comes into picture  they have solve all the problem ,you can upload the file download file and delete uploaded file

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#doc

Hope this help you Thank's.